# An Error with seting Assetlibrary.framwork

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, assets

Here's my big problem. My mapView is running with an error when I'm adding "Assetlibrary.Framwork". If I remove the library, my mapView is go fine.  Why? Here's my mapview code: (p.s I'm using storyboard)

```
.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MapView;

.m
viewdidload:
MapView.delegate = self;
[self setLocationManager:[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
if ((oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    || (oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude)) {

    coord.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    coord.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;


    region.center = coord;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;
    region.span = span;
}
```

And Here's my error:

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MapView.'

Am I setting my mapview twice? or something I did wrong?

Comment: right click on the map view in interface builder and see if you have attached it twice and one of the links is broken

Comment: solved!!  Appreciate for help!